# Questions about flooding.

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, questions

I have seen numerous questions dealing with yard flooding, which do not possess enough uniqueness to warrant their own question.  Personally I have seen these below...

[How do I stop backyard from flooding when it rains hard?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/how-do-i-stop-backyard-from-flooding-when-it-rains-hard)

[How to ensure proper drainage in a back yard](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/how-to-ensure-proper-drainage-in-a-back-yard/5228#5228)

Usually I just reference them to this answer [How to build a French drain?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq)  which is the second answer on the FAQ.

My question is this, are the above questions duplicates? Should the FAQ answer title be amended to attract the attention of people with this question, because chances are if they are asking this type of question, they won't know what a French Drain is anyway? Or should we continue to reference them to the FAQ as I have done? Or should be add more specific answers to the FAQ answer to cover multiple causes and solutions to more complex French Drain uses?

Comment: point them to the French drain question, and possibly edit the accepted answer to include a detailed list of causes and applications for the French drain.  Most likely the askers of the new questions have not read the French drain question, but if they read an answer that describes their situation they may feel more at ease with having their question merged or deleted.

Answer (score 3):

A bit of general advice:

If you see questions that you think are duplicate, but you don't have the reputation to vote A to close flag it for moderator attention. One of the moderators will then check out and and close as a duplicate if they agree. If I'm unsure I'll leave a comment pointing at the possible duplicate so other community members can review. You might consider doing that as well in the first instance.